# Magento attribute set not showing in store

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I'm working with Magento 1.8 and I have a problem which appears to be related to "Attribute Sets".
I had some attribute sets in my store, and now I added a new one. The problem is that products that are related to the new attribute set are not displayed in the store. Has anyone encountered this kind of problem?

Comment: Have you checked product visibility?

Comment: @Muk sure I have. Thanks for replying. The only difference I can tell between the two products is the attribute_set. is there a way to somehow hide products that have a certain attribute_set??